# How to query AWS load balancer log if there are terabytes of logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to query AWS load balancer log to automatically and on schedule send report for me.

I am using Amazon Athena and AWS Lambda to trigger Athena. I created data table based on guide here: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html`

However, I encounter following issues:

- Logs bucket increases in size day by day. And I notice if Athena query need more than 5 minutes to return result, sometimes, it produce "unknown error"
- Because the maximum timeout for AWS Lambda function is 15 minutes only. Therefore, I can not continue to increase Lambda function timeout to wait for Athena to return result (if in the case that Athena needs >15 minutes to return result, for example)

Can you guys suggest for me some better solution to solve my problem? I am thinking of using ELK stack but I have no experience in working with ELK, can you show me the advantages and disadvantages of ELK compared to the combo: AWS Lambda + AWS Athena? Thank you!

Comment: Seems you are dealing with big data issue, so have to use tools for that. Maybe AWS EMR would be helpful?

Comment: Do you need to run queries across the entire history of your logs, or just against the last few days/weeks?

Comment: @Parsifal currently, I run on yearly period. Last month/weeks is also OK, I think. However, I created table like steps in the guide that I refer link in my post. And I think that if I set s3 location is sth like /region/year/month. For example, month 3 data to pour into my data table, when in month 4, the table data will become incorrect. And do I have to re-create my data table? Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you *don't* need to keep your Lambda running while the Athena query executes. [StartQueryExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html) returns a query identifier that you can then poll with [GetQueryExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryExecution.html) to determine when the query finishes.

Of course, that doesn't work so well if you're invoking the query as part of a web request, but I recommend not doing that. And, unfortunately, I don't see that Athena is tied into CloudWatch Events, so you'll have to poll for query completion.

With that out of the way, the problem with reading access logs from Athena is that it isn't easy to partition them. The [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html) that AWS provides defines the table inside Athena, and the default partitioning scheme uses S3 paths that have segments `/column=value/`. However, ALB access logs use a simpler `yyyy/mm/dd` partitioning Scheme.

If you use AWS Glue, you can [define a table format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html#partition-projection-specifying-custom-s3-storage-locations) that uses this simpler scheme. I haven't done that so can't give you information other than what's in the docs.

Another alternative is to limit the amount of data in your bucket. This can save on storage costs as well as reduce query times. I would do something like the following:

- `Bucket_A` is the destination for access logs, and the source for your Athena queries. It has a life-cycle policy that deletes logs after 30 (or 45, or whatever) days.
- `Bucket_B` is set up to replicate logs from `Bucket_A` (so that you retain everything, forever). It immediately transitions all replicated files to "infrequent access" storage, which cuts the cost in half.

Elasticsearch is certainly a popular option. You'll need to convert the files in order to upload it. I haven't looked, but I'm sure there's a Logstash plugin that will do so. Depending on what you're looking to do for reporting, Elasticsearch may be better or worse than Athena.